# How to include the CSS and JS in pages?

Tags: php, html, include

I know how `<link type="stylesheet" href=".." />` and `<script type="text/javascript" src=".." />` work. But I have some truble understanding where they should be in context of W3C and also in context of good programming practice. I was many examples where these are in the header. I don't know why, but seems legit. But what impact has it when they're somewhere else in the HTML code?

Take for instance a `header` file, that is included by PHP into all pages of a website, and this header file has its own CSS\JS files. So they can either be included in the header file itself, and then there will be a `link` and a `script` tag in the middle of the HTML body of the page including the header file. Another option is putting these in the `head` section of each file, but then changes will have to be made in every single page.

My questions:

1. Where should the `link` and `script` tags be according to W3C?
2. What impact will it have if they are in the middle of the HTML body like in the example above?
3. What is the best solution in terms of good programming practice?
4. How do I make the following `include`, while having a W3C compliant page, and in a way that I don't have to update each page when I change the CSS\JS file.

   - Consider the included code snippet to be independent of the including page.

**Just for clearness a short example:** (Consider same situation also for a JS file)

header.html:

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css" />     <!--- Should this be here? --->
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li>Menu item1</li>
     <li>Menu item2</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

index.php:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css" />     <!--- Or should it be here? --->
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php include('header.html'); ?>
      <!--- Some HTML code ---->
   </body>
</html>
```

header.css:

```css
nav{ color: #00FF00; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple

```
Put Scripts at the Bottom.
Put Stylesheets at the Top
```

> The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.3) clearly states that stylesheets are to be
> included in the HEAD of the page: "Unlike A, [LINK] may only appear in
> the HEAD section of a document, although it may appear any number of
> times." Neither of the alternatives, the blank white screen or flash
> of unstyled content, are worth the risk. The optimal solution is to
> follow the HTML specification and load your stylesheets in the
> document HEAD.

For javascipts

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads.
> The [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4) suggests that browsers download no more
> than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images
> from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur
> in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't
> start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.

FYI:
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_top
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

**[EDIT]**
For your new question,

- Make that header.html to dynamic page.
- When ever that is being included, Read the data from output buffer (assuming you are not
  flushing it out) using ob_get_contents.
- Then you can inject the css file into the head part.
- Echo it.
- Clean the buffer with  ob_end_clean();

Some frameworks, like zend allows you to control this with the [helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript).

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a solution for the pointed problem that occurs when I include an independent code snippet into the main page?

Comment: why can't you move this "<html>
   <head>
  ........
   </head>
   <body>" code to header.html?

Comment: I can't move the code to the header because its holding HTML tags that I want to display. But I have CSS\JS that relates to it, which should not be in the BODY, so I want a way to include them without much headache. But I like the idea of defining dynamic page and inject something into the header. Can you put an example for that?
+1 anyway - and thanks! :)

Comment: pseudo code tells everything with clear hints. Use preg_replace to inject code. try it once. If you couldn't make, I will help you then. :)

Comment: OK I read the `ob_get_contents` manual, I think this may work. I'll play around with this later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets should always be in the Header. The style tag isn't allowed within body according to the W3C Spec. The only CSS you should put in the body is inline CSS, though I usually avoid inline styles.

Head is designed for (Quoting the W3C):

> "information about the current document, such as its title, keywords that may be useful to search engines, and other data that is not considered document content"
>   Via: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1

You put JS in the Header when you need to load them before the user loads the page. GoogleAnalytics or other Services or UI Elements could be loaded in the body. People who have slow internet connection will thank you. The content of your size will be load first, and not nice2have elements of your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>

     <link type="stylesheet" href=".." />
     <script type="text/javascript" src=".." />

  </head>
  <body>

     <!-- here html codes -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Link and script tag in the head section
example code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="YOUR URL" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR URL"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML tags-->
</body>
</html>
```